# Remove @XmlElement annotation while generating pojo from XSD

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, annotations, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I've a requirement to bind the XML content to String attribute of my pojo, and for that I've created my custom DomHandler to extract required part, something like below

```
<sample>
<color>red</color>
<content>
     <p>here is content <b>with bold</b></p>
</content>
</sample>
```

Which will map to pojo

```
@XmlRootElement
class Sample {
    @MyCustomAnnotation(value="abcde")
    @XmlElement(name="color")
    private String color;

    @MyCustomAnnotation(value="12345")
    @XmlElement(name="content")
    @XmlAnyElement(ContentHandler.class)
    private String content; 
}
```

I'm generating my pojos using XSD, also I've couple of custom annotations to be added to generated pojos so for that I'm using **maven-jaxb2-plugin**.

The problem is, it adds annotations as required along with @XmlElement which is mutually exclusive to @XmlAnyElement, is there any way to avoid adding @XmlElement annotation using XSD?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xjc:dom` to tell XJC that you want to handle this element as a DOM element. Example:

```
<jaxb:bindings 
    schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/owc/0.3.1/owsContext.xsd" 
    node="/xs:schema">

    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="net.opengis.owc.v_0_3_1"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>

    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='LayerType']//xs:element[@ref='kml:Document']">
        <xjc:dom/>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

Comment: using above the XmlElement got removed but the issue now is the plugin is not able to add my custom DomHandler to annotation and I get exception "It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings"

Comment: above happens because I'm trying to update XmlAnyElement with my custom DomHandler.

Comment: For instance I've below in my bindings.xjb
<jaxb:bindings node="xsd:complexType[@name='Sample']/xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='content']">
         <xjc:dom/>
      </jaxb:bindings>

      <jaxb:bindings node="xsd:complexType[@name='Sample']/xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='content']">
         <annox:annotate target="field">
            <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement"
                            value="com.lab49.ca.integration.daf.api.handler.RfqHandler"/>
         </annox:annotate>
      </jaxb:bindings>